# Specifying a minimum cluster size with Open Layers Clustering

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

With OpenLayers 3, how can I specify a minimum cluster size so that clusters with 5 map markers or less will not get clustered, but will instead display the individual map markers? Is there a way to do this within the cluster layer's ol.layer.Vector object?

```
let clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
   distance: CLUSTER_DISTANCE,
   source: features
});
let clusterLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({ 
   source: source, 
   style: function(feature, resolution) { } 
});
```

Comment: Have a look at http://viglino.github.io/OL3-AnimatedCluster/ for a possible solution.

Comment: I think you might be have to return an array of styles with a geometry in each one.

Answer (score 0):

You can check in the code how many features are there. If you have too many, you can create a cluster source based on the vector source you already have to add it a to a new vector layer. If not, a vector layer can be created with your existing vector source.

Since there is no method to set the source dynamically to a layer, your vector layer should be created with the desired source. If you want to see how it works with more than 5 features, just uncomment the commented lines.

```js
var features = [
    new ol.Feature({
     geometry: new ol.geom.Point([0,0])
    }),
    new ol.Feature({
     geometry: new ol.geom.Point([100000,500000])
    }),
    new ol.Feature({
     geometry: new ol.geom.Point([500000,100000])
    }),
    new ol.Feature({
     geometry: new ol.geom.Point([5000000,1000000])
    }),
    new ol.Feature({
     geometry: new ol.geom.Point([1000000,500000])
    })
    /*,new ol.Feature({
     geometry: new ol.geom.Point([1800000,800000])
    })*/
 ],
  source = new ol.source.Vector({
   features: features
  });

var layer;
if (features.length > 5) {
  var clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
    distance: parseInt(40, 10),
    source: source
  });

  var styleCache = {};
  layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: clusterSource,
    style: function(feature) {
      var size = feature.get('features').length;
      var style = styleCache[size];
      if (!style) {
        style = new ol.style.Style({
          image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 10,
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
              color: '#AAA'
            }),
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
              color: '#DDD'
            })
          }),
          text: new ol.style.Text({
            text: size.toString(),
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
              color: '#B144FF'
            })
          })
        });
        styleCache[size] = style;
      }
      return style;
    }
  });
} else {
  layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: source
  });
}

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
   new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
  }), 
    layer
  ],
  target: 'clusterMap',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/build/ol.js"></script>
<div id="clusterMap" class="map"></div>
```

Comment: I think you need a solution that would only cluster when 5 or more markers would get clustered and which works dynamically.  I believe this uses clustering when there are (initially) 5 or more features.  That is very different then the question.

Comment: In the question was not specified that it should occur dynamically, so this solution must solve the issue in a simple environment. Since the question owner didn't say anything else, I keep my answer as it is.